# Can I globally change colors in an SVG using illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, svg

I have an SVG graphic in illustrator. I want to replace colors, everywhere in the illustration, with different ones. Could I operate the color swatch to make the change? I'm looking for a global process. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

.svg file basically uses xml syntax to store image data, so in order to replace all colors you don't even need any graphic editor. The fastest way I can think of is:

1. Open the file in a text editor (Notepad should do it).
2. Use "Find and replace" tool (CTRL + H on windows).
3. As "Find text" enter the hex value you want to replace
4. As "Replace with" use the the new hex value.
5. Run find and replace on entire document.
6. Save file.